# pandas - how to create multiple columns in groupby with conditional?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I need to group a dataframe, but I need to create two columns, one that is a simple count and another that is a count with conditional, as in the example:

[image]

The `qtd_ok` column counts only those that have 'OK'

[image]

I tried this, but I do not know how to add the total count in the same `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['column1', 'column2', 'column3']).apply(lambda x : x['status'].sum() == 'OK')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create helper column `A` with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and then aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) functions `sum` for count only `OK` values and [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for count all values per groups:

```
df = (df.assign(A=(df['status']== 'OK'))
        .groupby(['column1', 'column2', 'column3'])['A']
        .agg([('qtd_ok','sum'),('qtd','size')])
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index())
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'column1':['a'] * 9,
        'column2':['a'] * 4 + ['b'] * 5,
        'column3':list('aaabaabbb'),
        'status':list('aabaaabba'),
})

print (df)
  column1 column2 column3 status
0       a       a       a      a
1       a       a       a      a
2       a       a       a      b
3       a       a       b      a
4       a       b       a      a
5       a       b       a      a
6       a       b       b      b
7       a       b       b      b
8       a       b       b      a

df = (df.assign(A=(df['status']== 'a'))
        .groupby(['column1', 'column2', 'column3'])['A']
        .agg([('qtd_ok','sum'),('qtd','size')])
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
  column1 column2 column3  qtd_ok  qtd
0       a       a       a       2    3
1       a       a       b       1    1
2       a       b       a       2    2
3       a       b       b       1    3
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea to count with groupby with lambda  which can further be enhanced ..

```
>>> df
  colum1    colum2    colum3 status
0  unit1  section1  content1     OK
1  unit1  section1  content1     OK
2  unit1  section1  content1  error
3  unit1  section1  content2     OK
4  unit1  section2  content1     OK
5  unit1  section2  content1     OK
6  unit1  section2  content2  error
7  unit1  section2  content2  error
8  unit1  section2  content2     OK
```

using groupby with lambda..

```
 >>> df.groupby(['colum1','colum2', 'colum3'])['status'].apply(lambda x: x[x.str.contains('OK', case=False)].count()).reset_index()
  colum1    colum2    colum3  status
0  unit1  section1  content1       2
1  unit1  section1  content2       1
2  unit1  section2  content1       2
3  unit1  section2  content2       1
```

Also can use `case=False` for ignorecase for `ok`.

Comment: OP expecting two output columns of GroupBy.

Answer (score 1):

#### [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)

You can use `pd.crosstab` with `margins=True`:

```
# data from @jezrael

list_of_lists = df.iloc[:, :-1].values.T.tolist()
condition = df['status'].eq('a')

res = pd.crosstab(list_of_lists, condition, margins=True)\
        .drop('All', level=0).reset_index()

print(res)

status column1 column2 column3  False  True  All
0            a       a       a      1     2    3
1            a       a       b      0     1    1
2            a       b       a      0     2    2
3            a       b       b      2     1    3
```